# Remote Notification Ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification

I have implemented Push Notification in my application.

I am receiving aps as follow's:

```
{
    aps =     {
        alert = "Bhai kaisa hai notification a rha hai!";
        customtitle = "Customtitle here";
        keyid = 8;
        sound = default;
    };
}
```

I want to pass keyid and customtitle to a view controller my code:

```
  NSString * titletopass = [userInfo objectForKey:@"customtitle"];
    NSString * keytopass = [userInfo objectForKey:@"keyid"];

    //NSString *titletopass=[getpass objectForKey:@"customtitle"];
    PostsDetailsViewController *obj = [[PostsDetailsViewController alloc]init];

    obj.Viewtitle = titletopass;
    obj.key=keytopass;

   NSString *identifier;
    identifier=@"postsdetails";
    UIStoryboard *    storyboardobj=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    obj = [storyboardobj instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:identifier];
    [self.window setRootViewController:obj];
```

It doesn't pass the data to viewcontroller, and keytopass + titletopass is empty as well.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you set `obj` to an instance of `PostDetailsViewController` you are then setting `obj` to the `postdetails` view controller instantiated from the storyboard.

If your intention is to use the storyboard, you should only create the instance from that. Once you have your instance you can set your properties.

For example:

```
NSString * titletopass = [[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"customtitle"];
NSString * keytopass = [[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"keyid"];

UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
PostsDetailsViewController *obj = (PostDetailsViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"postdetails"];

obj.Viewtitle = titletopass;
obj.key=keytopass;

[self.window setRootViewController:obj];
```

Comment: i am not able to get titletopass from my '{
    aps =     {
        alert = "Bhai kaisa hai notification a rha hai!";
        customtitle = "Customtitle here";
        keyid = 8;
        sound = default;
    };
}'

Comment: Edited the answer. You have those properties within the `aps` object.